# Roughness Reduction: Algorithm for smoothing out shapes

Tags: algorithm, math, maps, geometry

I have a a point list of some polygon shapes that I would like to include on the Google map I have on my page.

I've deleted as many unnecessary polygons from the raw data as possible and I am left with something like 12 now, but they are so detailed that it's causing issues.  Right now my file is 3mb and a lot of the users will be on dial up so I would like to get that down below a megabyte.  The shape of the polygons follows complex curves of rivers and consists of a lot of detail that isn't necessary for the general overview I'm trying to give my users.

Is there any good algorithm I could use that would look at the points and remove any within a certain threshold.  The end goal being to maintain the large features and get rid of the noisy little details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical algorithm for polygon simplification is *Ramer-Douglas-Peucker*

See for example [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) or [this blog post with an implementation in c#](http://ianqvist.blogspot.de/2010/05/ramer-douglas-peucker-polygon.html)

But if you just want to shrink a small amount of shapes once, it will probably be easiest to import the polygons into a graphics or CAD program that supports polygon simplification. Inkscape is free and should do the job

Comment: great that c# example is exactly what I needed.